# How to change the default permissions in Androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, android-permissions

I got a question about the "Androidmanifest.xml".
The default settings of the installation of an application is that
the application have permission to the SD-card and Telephone Calls.

How can I set that the application has only access to the SD-card and not to the Telephone Calls what is set as default?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify permissions besides Manifest. However, some custom ROMS allow you to alter installed app's permissions too, but then that is not something an ordinary user can/should follow.

Comment: So when i instal the application, its says he needs SD-card and Telephone Calls permission, so this cant be changed ?

Comment: yes, exactly... However, some custom ROMS allow you to alter installed app's permissions too. But that is not something an ordinary user can/should perform.

Comment: Is this not the solution? 

android.Manifest.permission
-> CALL_PHONE (Enable this one)

Answer (score 0):

If you would get root access on a device (by using an exploit or any other legit way), you could extract the **manifest file** from the installed application (apk file) then modify (add or remove permissions) **the manifest file** and then *repack* (inject) the application with the modified **manifest**. Next time the application would run it would get the new (modified) permissions.

Note: by any means this is not a standard procedure, or something a **Google Play** application should do!